# Modifying struct value using reflection and loop

Tags: go, reflection

I wanted to loop through a struct and modify fields value using reflection. How can I Set it?

```
func main() {
    x := struct {
        Foo string
        Bar int
    }{"foo", 2}
    StructCheck(Checker, x)
}

func Checker(s interface{}) interface{} {
    log.Println(s)
    return s
}

func StructCheck(check func(interface{}) interface{}, x interface{}) interface{} {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(x)
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        r := check(v.Field(i))
        w := reflect.ValueOf(&r).Elem()

        log.Println(w.Type(), w.CanSet())

        // v.Field(i).Set(reflect.ValueOf(w))

    }
    return v
}
```

Running Set() causes panic and shows :*reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must pass an addressable value to the function.

```
StructCheck(Checker, &x)
```

There's

Dereference the value in the StructCheck:

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(x).Elem() // Elem() gets value of ptr
```

There were some other issues. Here's the updated code:

```
func StructCheck(check func(interface{}) interface{}, x interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(x).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        r := check(v.Field(i).Interface())
        v.Field(i).Set(reflect.ValueOf(r))

    }
}
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bt5r3NlnuxT).

Comment: But when I try to cast it to x's struct it panics again any way to fix this? [link](https://play.golang.org/p/hPXFexYtTL4)

Comment: @ned I edited the answer to remove the return value from StructCheck.  Because the caller already has the value, there's no need to get the value again from the return value.